# What's the meaning of parameter "knots" in function "spmak" (in matlab)

Tags: matlab, spline

I have a data set which saved in matrix "data", it is of two-dimensional.  I want to fitting a curve with the function "spmak" in matlab using this data set. How to do ? 
    SPMAK(KNOTS,COEFS):the function prototype in matlab. what's the meaning of "knots" and "coefs"? How can I get the two parameter from the data matrix "data"?

Comment: how about reading http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/spmak.html?

Answer (score 0):

Because `knots` are the name for the points where the polynomial sections join up in a spline.

That's where the `knot` term comes from, a joining of the polynomial sections (tied together with a knot).

See the [mathematical spline entry on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) for more information.

A coefficient is a multiplicative factor for a term. For example, the expression `3x3 + x2 + 4x` has coefficients `3`, `1` and `4`.

Comment: thank you ! Then ,if i want to fitting a curve with a point set .How can i set parameter "knots" and "coefs" ?